# Access custom element of WPF ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I have this WPF ListView:

```
<ListView x:Name="OracleListView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Selected">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox Checked="Item_Checked" Unchecked="Item_Unchecked"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Name" />
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

I fill it like that:

```
OracleListView.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem{Content="Table A"});
OracleListView.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem{Content="Table B"});
OracleListView.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem{Content="Table C"});
```

So I have listview with 3 checkboxes and 3 strings. The question is:

How could I access checkbox column corresponding to selected item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily access the corresponding checkbox in the cheked event handler that you have already defined :

```
private void Item_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var checkBox = e.Source as CheckBox;    
}
```